# Parent two objects, without the child getting moved by the parent

Tags: constraints, parent

Is there a way to parent an object to another, such that the parent does not move the child when it moves? I thought of adding a "negative" Child-of constraint to compensate for movement by parent, but sadly that does not exist since constraint influence can't be set below 0. Any other suggestions?

Comment: uncheck x,y,z of the location in the child_of constraint

Comment: @Chebhou I might have phrased myself poorly - I need actual parenting (usable from scripting without all the constraint overhead), but I don't want the position of the child altered by the parent. Your solution does not work since the child is not actually a child of the parent then, it only has a constraint that does nothing.

Comment: you want to do this in script ?

Comment: Would it work to add an empty at the location of the child, and make the child copy the location of the empty?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't think that relevant. The point is I need the parent-child logical relationship, but want the child not to move.

Comment: then the constraint will do then

Comment: @someonewithpc Well, um... I'll check.

Comment: @Chebhou No, since there is no way to reference the child from the parent.

Comment: @someonewithpc Clever, it works! Make an answer if you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done fairly quickly; what you need to do is and an empty to the location of the child, and then make the child copy the location of the empty, using a constraint — now you can safely parent both objects and the child won't move.

You can do this by:

1. While in Edit mode, and with the child selected, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to selected*
2. Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Empty* > *Plain Axis*
3. Selecting the child, going to the *Constraints* tab of the *Properties* window and adding a  *Copy Location* constraint, with the target set to the empty created earlier

Comment: This single answer has opened my eyes to the next level of Blendering! :)