# Can I move the parent object without moving the child?

Tags: animation, rigging, parent

I'm doing an animation and I need to move the parent without moving the child - can I do this without unparenting them, because it messes up the rig and the animation.

Let's use this rig here:

[image]

Is there a way to rotate the selected bone without moving the legs?

[image]

Comment: Please provide screenshots of the problem and upload a blend file if possible

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE. maybe [This](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/30288/19287) helps. You also may have a look here [How to ask a good Question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and also consider the [search function](http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?) is a loyal pal :)

Comment: How can I upload the .blend file? Also I found out that you can use the child of constraint and change the influence to 'toggle' the child/parent relationship on and off, however the problem with that is now every time I change the influence, the child will become more/less like the parent and go to where the parent is. Is there a way to simply turn the 'link' on and off so that I can move the parent separate from the child when needed but turn it on when I don't?